# How can I do a recursive find and replace from the command shell?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find-and-replace

Using a shell like bash or zshell, how can I do a recursive 'find and replace'? In other words, I want to replace every occurrence of '/path/to/folder' with '/other/dir' in all files in this directory and its subdirectories.

This is essentially the same question as the original from this name but what I need to know is what happens if the text you want to replace has slashes in it like the above examples? Can I just paste my code in the find/replace spot into the args? Or do I have to do something else???

All of this will be done over ssh to Ubuntu server.

Thanks!

Comment: your question is relly not clear maybe it will help if you add the code you like to use - if you have trouble with the slashes escaping them may help

Comment: The thing is that I know nothing about RegEx. Is there a place to learn it?

Comment: yes there is a lot of stuff about regex in the internet but take care about the fact that regex is not equal to regex (it depends a lot on the programming/script language your using/you'd like to use)   -  do you just want to do this a visual way (just show it on terminal/console) or do you wan't it to also change the directory in real (move files/rename folders)???

Comment: I need to do it ALL in the console. It is on Godaddy servers through SSH

Comment: ok but what would you like to do just get a output to save in a text file or do an actual task e.g moving/renaming multiple files?

Comment: See the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) and [`sed`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/sed.1.php):

```
find . exec sed -i .bak 's,/path/to/folder,/other/dir,g' \;
```

- You can also use `awk` or `perl` instead of `sed` - pick whatever you like.
- You can pass options to `find` to limit the file you operate on &c

Comment: Thanks! I know how to do the find part it was the wording of sed that was the issue. I am going to test it now :)

Comment: Thanks! I used it like this:`find html -name ".htaccess" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i `` -e 's,/dir/with/a/lot/of/subs,/other/dir/with/some/more/subs,g'`

Comment: It worked like a charm and that just took 200+ file edits of my back :)